# Facebook Authorization error when password changed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

We are connecting to facebook via the api secret key etc… but when ever a fb user changes their password the tool disconnect… How can we stop this from happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. When a user changes their password, all access tokens are revoked for all applications that the user has installed.

There is nothing you can do to prevent a user from changing their password. What you will be able to do is detect an invalid token when the user arrives and re-authenticate them to generate a new token.

Comment: You need to check if the user is authenticated - same process as logging into the application. Your application is not broken - you just need to add some more logic to your code to handle this situation...

Comment: Can you tell me how can i get app access token using ajax i do not want to use php ?.

Comment: Hmm.. The problem with that is that you'll have to embed your application secret on the client side - you don't want that because then any user can impersonate your application...  Application access tokens should only ever be used on the server where users can not see them...